# How to create crawl rules to exclude root folder content but crawl subfolders

Tags: 2010, crawling, crawl-rules

I've been trying to crawl an external site using SharePoint 2010 in which I'm only interested in crawling results for the content stored in various subfolders underneath a root path.

The root path is of the form: `http://hostname/folder/`

Subfolders are: `http://hostname/folder/folderA http://hostname/folder/folderB`, etc.

My current crawl rules are as follows:

```
http://hostname/folder/*.html exclude
http://hostname/folder/*/* include
```

Can anyone help in defining the right set of rules using regEx so:

```
http://hostname/folder/a.html is excluded and
http://hostname/folder/folderA/b.html is included
```

Comment: How many subfolders you have?

Comment: 50+ but they dynamically change